# how to receive data from a php file into angularjs code

Tags: php, angularjs

I am calling the php file from js code from http.get in angularjs. On Success function the result should be received in parameter. But it is showing that null is received.If I use simple echo with a string param that is received but the sql result is not received in function. The query and connection is correct. I am unable to find the error.

js file

```
 app.controller('HomeController',function($scope,$http){
 $scope.message="Home";

 $http.get('get.php').
    success(function(data) {
        debugger;
        $scope.users = data;
       });

 });
```

php file

```
<?php
$database = "firstdatabase"; //database name
$con      = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$state = "SELECT rollno ,name, dept FROM student";

 $result = mysqli_query($con, $state);


 if ($result) {


$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //$r[] = $row['rollno'];
    //$n[]= $row['name'];
    //$d[] = $row['dept'];
    $arr[] = $row;

 }
//$rows = array();
//    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
//        $rows[]=$row['name'];
//    }

 }

 echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($arr));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` statement is in the last line, However in the middle of your php code, you've placed an unconditional `exit();` statement that's preventing this script to execute completely and thus is preventing it to `echo` the response.

[image]

Comment: By error I meant that I am still receiving null in my js function

Comment: You've multiple `exit()` statements, Have you removed them all? Plus you should also remove `echo ($name)` that I've encircled in the picture because it will create problem since you're echoing complete JSON below

Comment: I have updated the file but same issue exists that i am receiving null on the other end

Comment: Please visit `www.yourdomain.com/get.php` and tell me what's the output.